# recursive function in vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++17

i am learning data structure on c++ and i have come through one thing which is hard for me to understand or get concept.

I am just putting question to give better context.

https://leetcode.com/problems/frequency-of-the-most-frequent-element/

The frequency of an element is the number of times it occurs in an array.
You are given an integer array nums and an integer k. In one operation, you can choose an index of nums and increment the element at that index by 1.
Return the maximum possible frequency of an element after performing at most k operations.

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,4], k = 5
Output: 3
Explanation: Increment the first element three times and the second element two times to 
make nums = [4,4,4].
4 has a frequency of 3.
```

this is the code given to complete:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxFrequency(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        
    }
};
```

i want to solve this problem by recursive first but my problem here is that the function is getting reference of a vector as a parameter so if i change the value inside the function, it will change the original vector.

I am not able to think how can i make different recursion with different choices because it is not pass by value.

Any help please !!

Comment: you could change it back before returning. You could be sneaky and write `} int maxFrequency2(vector<int> nums, int k) {`

Comment: i can't change the function parameter, i conly add code into that given code

Comment: you could be sneaky and write `} int maxFrequency2(vector<int> nums, int k) {`

Comment: you could change the vector and then change it back before returning

Comment: you could write the function in a way that's not recursive

Comment: Nothing says you can't add more functions to the class, and can't have `maxFrequency` call those new functions.

Comment: you meant to say that i should call another function with vector pass as a value? does *nums mean i have that vector with value but not by reference?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a temporary vector that has the same elements as the given vector nums and then explore all possibilities using recursion.
We can try running the following recursive code:

```
class Solution {
int helper(int i,vector<int>& nums,vector<int> temp, int k) {
    if(k==0){
        unordered_map<int,int>freqMap;
        for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
            freqMap[temp[i]]++;
        }
        int maxFreq=0;
        for(auto it:freqMap){
        maxFreq=max(maxFreq,it.second);
    }
    return maxFreq;
    }
    if(i<0) return 0;
    temp[i]+=1;
    int take=helper(i,nums,temp,k-1); //choose current index element
    temp[i]-=1;
    int not_take=helper(i-1,nums,temp,k); //skip current index element
    return max(take,not_take);
}

public:
int maxFrequency(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    vector<int> temp=nums //temporary vector having same numbers as nums
    return helper(nums.size()-1,nums,temp,k);
    }
};
```

Although the code uses a brute force approach and is not optimised, but it sets out the initial logic for further solving and optimising the problem.